# Using apply on a multidimensional array in R

Tags: r

I am wondering how to use apply on a multidimensional array.  I have something like the following:

```
A <- array(0, c(2, 2, 5))
for(i in 1:5) {
  A[, , i] <- matrix(rnorm(4), 2, 2)
}
```

I would like to take the average of those slices to get a single 2 by 2 matrix.  Any way I come up with is pretty kludgy.

I was hoping to be able to use apply, like I would if I wanted the average say of the columns of a matrix:

```
B <- matrix(rnorm(10), 5, 2)
B.mean <- apply(B, 2, mean)
```

But this doesn't seem to work the way I think it might with 3D arrays:

```
A.mean <- apply(A, 3, mean)
```

I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
A.mean <- apply(A, c(1,2), mean)
```

Comment: Perfect!  And it was right there in the help file for array, but I didn't see it until you pointed it out, even having looked at it.  Thank you!

Comment: In general, the `margin` parameter of `apply` should be a vector of dimensions you want to preserve, rather than collapse.

Comment: what about: mean.data.frame(A) ?

Comment: @ncray, @mbq: this qualifies as an R gotcha, since `apply(,margin,)` specifies the dimensions we **don't** want to operate on rather than the ones we do. (For intuitiveness, you could custom-define your own `apply_on()` which specifies the dimensions you **do** want to operate on.)

Comment: @smci: no, I think it's correct, if you have an array of n rows, by m columns, and you want to apply a `mean` function to each row, then you over the first dimension (rows: `apply(x, c(1), mean)`), and you get back an n-dimensional vector (ie. the number of rows). It's pretty hard to get your head around generalising this to higher dimensional arrays though..