# Using apply on multidimensional array in R

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, apply

I have a three-dimensional array. The first matrix in the array is a matrix of correlation values, the second is a matrix of p values for those correlation values. I would like to choose the column for which each row has a positive and most significant correlation. I have done this previously only looking at the p-value matrix but I need to choose only positive correlations as well.

Example from only p-value matrix:

```
Assignments_Cor <- apply(Pmatrix,1,function(x) which(x <= .05 & x==min(x)))
```

An array containing both Correlation and p-value matrices:

```
Cor_array <- array(c(CorMatrix,Pmatrix), dim = c(564381,40,2))
```

Example of the array:

```
Cor_array[1:3,,]
, , 1

           [,1]     [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]       [,7]       [,8]       [,9]      [,10]       [,11]        [,12]
[1,] 0.05025017 0.151692 -0.1848826 0.4574867 0.6334903 0.1339035 0.07913106 -0.0256966 -0.2809419 -0.1032585 -0.09840864 5.568632e-05
[2,] 0.05025017 0.151692 -0.1848826 0.4574867 0.6334903 0.1339035 0.07913106 -0.0256966 -0.2809419 -0.1032585 -0.09840864 5.568632e-05
[3,] 0.05025017 0.151692 -0.1848826 0.4574867 0.6334903 0.1339035 0.07913106 -0.0256966 -0.2809419 -0.1032585 -0.09840864 5.568632e-05
            [,13]      [,14]      [,15]      [,16]      [,17]      [,18]     [,19]      [,20]     [,21]      [,22]       [,23]      [,24]
[1,] 0.0005633181 0.02967809 0.08584057 0.06479591 0.02071323 -0.1235664 0.3390882 0.04291397 0.1011558 0.08703663 -0.01512865 -0.1367294
[2,] 0.0005633181 0.02967809 0.08584057 0.06479591 0.02071323 -0.1235664 0.3390882 0.04291397 0.1011558 0.08703663 -0.01512865 -0.1367294
[3,] 0.0005633181 0.02967809 0.08584057 0.06479591 0.02071323 -0.1235664 0.3390882 0.04291397 0.1011558 0.08703663 -0.01512865 -0.1367294
         [,25]      [,26]       [,27]     [,28]     [,29]      [,30]      [,31]      [,32]      [,33]     [,34]      [,35]      [,36]
[1,] 0.1275199 0.06567954 -0.02009797 0.1533013 0.1641937 0.06995981 0.02188142 -0.1051497 0.06470244 0.3001694 0.02796141 0.08276204
[2,] 0.1275199 0.06567954 -0.02009797 0.1533013 0.1641937 0.06995981 0.02188142 -0.1051497 0.06470244 0.3001694 0.02796141 0.08276204
[3,] 0.1275199 0.06567954 -0.02009797 0.1533013 0.1641937 0.06995981 0.02188142 -0.1051497 0.06470244 0.3001694 0.02796141 0.08276204
           [,37]     [,38]    [,39]       [,40]
[1,] -0.03737224 0.0116931 0.130225 -0.02056016
[2,] -0.03737224 0.0116931 0.130225 -0.02056016
[3,] -0.03737224 0.0116931 0.130225 -0.02056016

, , 2

          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]      [,4]       [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]     [,11]    [,12]     [,13]
[1,] 0.8767529 0.6379141 0.565124 0.1348092 0.02699434 0.6782239 0.8068801 0.9368179 0.3764017 0.7494653 0.7609224 0.999863 0.9986137
[2,] 0.8767529 0.6379141 0.565124 0.1348092 0.02699434 0.6782239 0.8068801 0.9368179 0.3764017 0.7494653 0.7609224 0.999863 0.9986137
[3,] 0.8767529 0.6379141 0.565124 0.1348092 0.02699434 0.6782239 0.8068801 0.9368179 0.3764017 0.7494653 0.7609224 0.999863 0.9986137
         [,14]     [,15]     [,16]     [,17]     [,18]     [,19]     [,20]     [,21]    [,22]     [,23]     [,24]     [,25]     [,26]
[1,] 0.9270498 0.7908135 0.8414306 0.9490552 0.7020171 0.2809266 0.8946503 0.7544271 0.787957 0.9627807 0.6717649 0.6928868 0.8392928
[2,] 0.9270498 0.7908135 0.8414306 0.9490552 0.7020171 0.2809266 0.8946503 0.7544271 0.787957 0.9627807 0.6717649 0.6928868 0.8392928
[3,] 0.9270498 0.7908135 0.8414306 0.9490552 0.7020171 0.2809266 0.8946503 0.7544271 0.787957 0.9627807 0.6717649 0.6928868 0.8392928
         [,27]     [,28]     [,29]     [,30]     [,31]     [,32]     [,33]     [,34]     [,35]     [,36]     [,37]     [,38]    [,39]
[1,] 0.9505668 0.6343094 0.6101065 0.8289519 0.9461855 0.7450102 0.8416568 0.3431528 0.9312604 0.7981765 0.9082003 0.9712292 0.686661
[2,] 0.9505668 0.6343094 0.6101065 0.8289519 0.9461855 0.7450102 0.8416568 0.3431528 0.9312604 0.7981765 0.9082003 0.9712292 0.686661
[3,] 0.9505668 0.6343094 0.6101065 0.8289519 0.9461855 0.7450102 0.8416568 0.3431528 0.9312604 0.7981765 0.9082003 0.9712292 0.686661
         [,40]
[1,] 0.9494312
[2,] 0.9494312
[3,] 0.9494312


structure(c(0.0502501693988644, 0.0502501693988641, 0.050250169398864, 
0.151692009166368, 0.151692009166368, 0.151692009166367, -0.184882599833557, 
-0.184882599833556, -0.184882599833556, 0.457486739533705, 0.457486739533705, 
0.457486739533705, 0.633490267138363, 0.633490267138363, 0.633490267138363, 
0.13390346680798, 0.13390346680798, 0.13390346680798, 0.0791310555319431, 
0.0791310555319426, 0.0791310555319425, -0.0256965953225384, 
-0.0256965953225386, -0.0256965953225386, -0.280941903238814, 
-0.280941903238813, -0.280941903238813, -0.103258518571999, -0.103258518571998, 
-0.103258518571998, -0.0984086417763842, -0.0984086417763844, 
-0.0984086417763844, 5.56863238651669e-05, 5.56863238655451e-05, 
5.56863238656109e-05, 0.000563318102446287, 0.000563318102446655, 
0.000563318102446727, 0.0296780938422325, 0.0296780938422335, 
0.0296780938422337, 0.0858405742363955, 0.0858405742363964, 0.0858405742363965, 
0.0647959077206117, 0.0647959077206113, 0.0647959077206112, 0.0207132277202097, 
0.0207132277202095, 0.0207132277202094, -0.123566367605933, -0.123566367605933, 
-0.123566367605933, 0.339088189112549, 0.339088189112549, 0.339088189112549, 
0.0429139743381961, 0.0429139743381953, 0.0429139743381951, 0.101155788270212, 
0.101155788270213, 0.101155788270213, 0.0870366270184804, 0.0870366270184799, 
0.0870366270184799, -0.0151286537942279, -0.015128653794228, 
-0.015128653794228, -0.136729446022951, -0.136729446022951, -0.136729446022951, 
0.127519897933732, 0.127519897933733, 0.127519897933733, 0.0656795357491338, 
0.0656795357491338, 0.0656795357491338, -0.0200979711493121, 
-0.0200979711493123, -0.0200979711493124, 0.153301329950428, 
0.153301329950428, 0.153301329950428, 0.164193663850843, 0.164193663850843, 
0.164193663850842, 0.0699598078601379, 0.0699598078601379, 0.0699598078601379, 
0.0218814243067889, 0.0218814243067892, 0.0218814243067893, -0.105149668955256, 
-0.105149668955257, -0.105149668955257, 0.0647024417919247, 0.064702441791925, 
0.064702441791925, 0.300169352611791, 0.300169352611791, 0.300169352611791, 
0.0279614122795903, 0.027961412279591, 0.0279614122795911, 0.0827620384095535, 
0.0827620384095534, 0.0827620384095534, -0.0373722422368233, 
-0.0373722422368239, -0.037372242236824, 0.0116931048088869, 
0.0116931048088874, 0.0116931048088875, 0.13022503266764, 0.13022503266764, 
0.13022503266764, -0.0205601573534089, -0.0205601573534081, -0.0205601573534079, 
0.876752872328793, 0.876752872328794, 0.876752872328794, 0.637914059576286, 
0.637914059576288, 0.637914059576288, 0.565123994635566, 0.565123994635567, 
0.565123994635567, 0.134809211200425, 0.134809211200425, 0.134809211200425, 
0.0269943418212044, 0.0269943418212044, 0.0269943418212044, 0.678223869263038, 
0.678223869263038, 0.678223869263038, 0.806880131717569, 0.80688013171757, 
0.806880131717571, 0.93681792762169, 0.93681792762169, 0.93681792762169, 
0.376401674285645, 0.376401674285647, 0.376401674285647, 0.749465324483993, 
0.749465324483994, 0.749465324483994, 0.760922433768518, 0.760922433768518, 
0.760922433768518, 0.99986295943793, 0.999862959437929, 0.999862959437929, 
0.998613709943805, 0.998613709943804, 0.998613709943804, 0.92704977032553, 
0.927049770325527, 0.927049770325527, 0.79081346941971, 0.790813469419708, 
0.790813469419708, 0.841430606294886, 0.841430606294887, 0.841430606294887, 
0.949055189573776, 0.949055189573777, 0.949055189573777, 0.70201714332711, 
0.70201714332711, 0.70201714332711, 0.280926561073373, 0.280926561073374, 
0.280926561073374, 0.894650281557856, 0.894650281557858, 0.894650281557859, 
0.754427144601464, 0.754427144601464, 0.754427144601464, 0.78795704692359, 
0.787957046923591, 0.787957046923591, 0.962780687830925, 0.962780687830925, 
0.962780687830925, 0.671764873371626, 0.671764873371626, 0.671764873371626, 
0.692886829156112, 0.692886829156112, 0.692886829156111, 0.839292837080267, 
0.839292837080267, 0.839292837080267, 0.950566777097027, 0.950566777097026, 
0.950566777097026, 0.634309375188224, 0.634309375188224, 0.634309375188224, 
0.610106477900623, 0.610106477900624, 0.610106477900624, 0.828951879003462, 
0.828951879003463, 0.828951879003463, 0.94618554441019, 0.946185544410189, 
0.946185544410189, 0.745010199773543, 0.745010199773542, 0.745010199773542, 
0.841656787001919, 0.841656787001918, 0.841656787001918, 0.343152837630054, 
0.343152837630053, 0.343152837630053, 0.931260394121355, 0.931260394121353, 
0.931260394121353, 0.798176452055549, 0.798176452055549, 0.798176452055549, 
0.908200304636095, 0.908200304636093, 0.908200304636093, 0.971229245245656, 
0.971229245245654, 0.971229245245654, 0.686661031492219, 0.68666103149222, 
0.68666103149222, 0.949431244886679, 0.949431244886681, 0.949431244886681
), .Dim = c(3L, 40L, 2L))
```

I don't have much experience working with arrays or apply() and I'm pretty confused about how I'd call the same row in both matrices and apply these conditionals. So ideally these three rows should all return column 5 as the column in which each row has a positive and significant correlation.

I've been able to implement a solution using a for loop but I'd still like to use apply to do this more efficiently. Using the example first three rows of the array I've given above.

```
for (row in 1:3) {
    print(which(Cor_array [row,,1] > 0 & Cor_array [row,,2] <= .05 & Cor_array [row,,2]==min(Cor_array [row,,2])))
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of your 3d array?

Comment: @thelatemail Does that help?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @RonakShah I've added dput output, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using apply on a multidimensional array in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197330/using-apply-on-a-multidimensional-array-in-r)

Comment: @tester not really, I was just confused on how to call the row but only in specific matrices of the array. So in this answer, when they apply the function across all matrices in the array it didn't really help clear up the confusion I was having

Answer (score 0):

After getting a bit more familiar with apply and arrays here's what I got to work.

```
apply(Cor_array,1,function(x) which(x[,1] > 0 & x[,2] <= .05 & x[,2]==min(x[,2])))
```